# How to link from mail server to browser?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, behat, mink

I want to redirect from mail to browser. Requirement is like, I have a mail that contains one link, after clicking on that link it will redirect to the browser. To achieve this I configured my base url on mail server for example `microsoft.outlook.com`. So when I click a link it will go to `http://abcd.com/registration/success` url. So how can I configure to switching the base url like this. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you be more concise? You need to change base url or you need to navigate to base url?

Comment: I want to navigate from microsoft.outlook.com to http://abcd.com/registration/success after clicking on a link in the mail

Answer (score 0):

For navigating to another page you can use:

```
I am on "abcd.com/registration/success"
```

or from a context:

```
$this->getSession()->visit('abcd.com/registration/success');
```

If the link is dynamic you could create a step for this: get the link and navigate to it.

You could name the step: 'I confirm the registration' or use any snippet that is helpful to you.

For getting the link you could use a method to get the href attribute, find the element and use getAttribute('href') and save it to a variable.
After this you could use the visit method to visit that link.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually in my case the navigating url is dynamic one. I cant able to give each time that particular url to visit. So is there any generic method to do this. Mail contains a link which will leads to success of the registration. So that link is always different for different users.